# Computing maximum dimension of a vector subspace given that it's every element is a symmetric matrix and is closed under matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, vector-spaces, symmetric-matrices

> Q. Let $S$ be a subspace of the vector space of all $11 \times 11$ real matrices such that (i) every matrix in $S$ is symmetric and (ii) $S$ is closed under matrix multiplication. What is the maximum possible dimension of $S$?

**Attempt :** Subspace of symmetric matrices has dimension $\frac {n(n+1)}2$ for the vector space of $n \times n$ matrices.

Here in this case, it is $\frac {11\times 12}2=66$.

Next, using (ii) we have that $(AB)^T=AB$. But $(AB)^T=B^T A^T=BA. (\because A^T=A, B^T=B)$. Hence $AB=BA$. So we conclude that elements in $S$ commute with each other.

In case of vector spaces of $2\times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrices, I found that only diagonal matrices commute with each other.

For e.g. in $2 \times 2$ case, I just multiplied the basis elements of the subspace of symmetric matrices $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\cdot
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 1  \\
        \end{pmatrix} \cdot  \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$ but $$ \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix} \cdot  \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        1 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        1 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Similarly checking the commutativity of basis elements  of space of $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrices also gives only the space of diagonal matrices as a candidate having commuting elements.

Like, $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Hence the vector space of all diagonal matrices satisfies (i) & (ii). Thus minimum possible 'maximum dimension' of $S$ is $11$. So we have that $11 \le \max \dim S \lt 66$.

Am I in right direction so far? What can be my next step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, then $AB$ symmetric means $AB=(AB)^T=B^TA^T=BA$. All the matrices therefore commute. A symmetric
real matrix is diagonalisable, and pairwise commuting real matrices
are simultaneously diagonalisable. So the dimension of such a space is
at most $11$.

Comment: I didn't understand that "A symmetric real matrix is diagonalisable, and pairwise commuting real matrices are simultaneously diagonalisable.So the dimension of such a space is at most 11." I know symmetric matrices are diagonalisable and also since the matrices of $S$ commute, then one is diagonalisable iff the other is so. But since all of the elements in $S$ are symmetric themselves then all of them are diagonalisable without using commutativity at all. Then how did you conclude that the dimension of $S$ is at most $11$ ?. What is my mistake in understanding here?

Comment: @VikrantDesai You are wrong that if two matrices commute and the first is diagonalisable then so is the second (for instance the first one coul be zero, or the identity). What is true is that if two matrices are both diagonalisable and commute, then they are _simultaneously_ diagonalisable, which means that there is _one_ change of basis that makes both matrices diagonalisable. This is even true with more than two (diagonalisable) matrices, as long as they are pairwise commuting. Then a single change of basis maps the whole space of commuting matrices into the dim=11 space of diagonal matrices

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Okay, I see. I didn't know this concept *simultaneous diagonalizability*. I have checked Wikipedia and quite understood it. So you and LordSharktheUnknown are saying that there exists a single invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1} AP=\text {diagonal matrix} \; \forall \; A \in S$. Defining a map $f : S \to D$ such that $f(A)=P^{-1} AP \; \forall \; A \in S$ gives images in space of diagonal matrices and is onto. So the dimension for $S$ is at most $11$? What about the elements in $S$? Surely all of them are diagonal matrices.

Comment: Actually, what is important is that $f$ is injective (or "into"), so that $\dim(S)\leq\dim(D)=11$. And the elements $A$ of $S$ need not be diagonal, it's just $f(A)$ that is diagonal.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I found myself that $f$ is a linear transformation. But more than that it is a ring homomorphism as well. $f(A+B)=P^{-1} (A+B) P=P^{-1} A P + P^{-1} BP=f(A)+f(B), f(\lambda A)=P^{-1} \lambda A P=\lambda P^{-1} AP=\lambda f(A), f(AB)=P^{-1} AB P=P^{-1} AP P^{-1} BP=f(A)f(B).$  Verified $f$ is one-one by showing $f(A)=f(B) \Rightarrow P^{-1} AP=P^{-1} BP \Rightarrow A=B$. So now everything is clear to me. Thanks. +1